# Hide 1 line of text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two lines of code in a PHP file

```
<div align="center">The quick brown fox</div>
<div align="center">jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

How can I hide only the first line of text displayed with CSS?

Comment: `div[align="center"]:first-child {display: none;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
div[align="center"]:first-child {
       display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

div:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

It makes use of the `nth-of-type` ([Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)) selector

Answer (score -2):

```
<div align="center" hidden="yes">The quick brown fox</div>
<div align="center">jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

1. only add `hidden="yes"`
2. use CSS  `display="none";`